# Hazard ratio for continuous variable

Tags: hazard

I have a HR of 0.65 (0.46-0.92) and my explanatory variable is age (weeks of age). Time, event ~ age modeled with a flexible semiparametric model.
My interpretation is that for each week elapsed, there is a 35% decreased probability to the event ocurr.
However, at the end of the follow up, there are the same number of individuals that have the event (~90%). 
Am I using the correct words to summarized the HR interpretation?

Comment: You should specify what model exactly.

Comment: Yes please tell us the full model, and note that hazard models do not model probabilities but rather instantaneous failure rates (hazards) and their ratios.  There is a chapter in the [RMS book and course notes](http://fharrell.com/links) for displaying results when you have nonlinear predictor effects.  To make it easier I usually use regression splines instead of nonparametric smoothers.

Comment: fit_flexibleSpline <- flexsurvspline(Surv(t_0, t_1, event) ~ age_weeks, scale="hazard", data=mydata)